# Phrase concerning "concealing a weapon"

Tags: phrases, idioms

I am having trouble finding the right way to describe the following: *a man not having a revolver "tucked away in the pants."* I would like this to include the idea that *"if he had one, you wouldn't see it anyway, but he doesn't,"* I also need to include the *"in the pants"* or *"in the belt"*(?), as this is for a translation.

Is there any phrase describing this situation?

Comment: Let me see if I understand, you are looking for a way to say that a man might or might not be carrying a weapon on his person (either in his pants or in his belt) but it is impossible to tell because of what he is wearing?

Answer (score 3):

> He didn't have a gun on his belt, though one wouldn't have noticed it there if he had.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe..."Not that it would be visible underneath the fabric of his pants, but he did not have a revolver on him".
or
"While he could've easily concealed a revolver inside his pants/under his belt, he was not carrying one".